# Best Practice to interact with files (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server

I want to upload a JSON file to my Server (I use NodeJS and 'http' Module as Web Server). With the NPM module 'formidable', I was able to receive that file from the user and save it on my server.

Now I want to use informations from that file and show a statistical chart on the website.
The problem is that I dont know how to embed that file, so that I can use these informations to create a chart on the website because NodeJS is serverside and I can't use modules like 'fs' for the client side code. I tried WebPack, so that I am able to use 'fs' but it didn't work.

What is the best way to realize this?

Comment: You can place it in a static folder no ? And access it from client side...

Comment: Fs would not be appropriate anyway. You need to create a response on the server that contains the chart data

Answer (score 0):

Could you read the file into a string on your server using php, and then bring it in on the client side with JQuery?  You'll need to go download, and include JQuery on your page, like this:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"; type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So something like this on your server:

fileread.php

```
<?php
$myinfo = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/myfile.txt');
echo $myinfo;
?>
```

And on the webpage/client side, read in using JQuery:

```
var path="http://www.example.com/fileread.php"
    $.get(path, function(data){
    content= data;
    alert(content);
    //then do whatever you need to with content...
    };
```